# USB device unknown, not migrated, configured (null), cannot specify driver

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, drivers

I have a USB dongle that worked fine in the past, but recently started failing. I reinstalled the drivers with no change. The same drivers and device work on a different machine, so it is something with this PC.

When installed, Windows 10 now says it's an unknown device. The device event log says "Device USB\VID_... could not be migrated" and "Device USB\VID_... was configured. Driver Name: null" which means it has no driver loaded. Uninstalling and reinserting has no effect.

Clicking on [Update Driver] does nothing at all, even though the status window says:

```
The drivers for this device are not installed. (Code 28)
There are no compatible drivers for this device.
To find a driver for this device, click Update Driver.
```

Is there any way to specify the driver for this device? Is there a way to completely purge the device and driver from Windows memory and start over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Microsoft Windows 10 issue. You may want to follow this thread, [What is the meaning of 'device could not be migrated' in device manager?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/what-is-the-meaning-of-device-could-not-be/242f471f-9b20-4981-bec5-a236a235b25b?page=2)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after following Microsoft's and third party tutorials (except for the steps involving upgrading BIOS and similar sensitive stuff), I couldn't solve the issue, but eventually solved it in a so much easier way: I uninstalled the driver as well as the USB Composite Device (which for some reason showed up twice), disconnected the wireless mouse USB antenna from my laptop, restarted the system, placed the USB antenna back into the USB port, Windows reinstalled it as a newly found device, and the "not migrated" message didn't show anymore in events, and the mouse started working. Maybe you should try this first, as it's way less risky than upgrading BIOS.
USB Composite device kept on showing duplicated anyway, so that appears to be a normal behavior.